# How to change how IE / Chrome opens a file in-browser?

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, pdf, adobe

So here's the story. At my company, you can access previous pay statements online via a payroll website. When you go to look at a statement, it will open the statement in-browser via a pdf viewer. When working properly, it will usually ask if you want to blank out all the data or not (which... why would you want to? the point is to look at your statement). Now, this worked fine when checking it out in Adobe Reader; you'd just click "yes, show data" and everything displays fine, it can be printed, etc. But the company decided that instead of getting Acrobat for editing pdf files, that the better (cheaper) option is to get a cheap/free alternative called "Nuance" something or other. Two users installed this program, and now the browsers open pdfs in-browser with Nuance instead of Adobe Reader. This is a problem, because Nuance doesn't show the option of hiding or showing data like Reader did; rather, it just chooses the "no" option, which results in a blank template pdf coming up.

Now, this whole problem could be solved if we could just get the browsers to use Reader to open pdf files in-browser... obviously it's not a problem if you could download the pdf, but the site doesn't seem to allow you to download the pdf files. We've tried just about everything we could think of, short of uninstalling Nuance altogether, to get IE or Chrome to open pdf files with Reader, but even with a full IE reset, it uses Nuance to open pdfs inside the browser. Changing the default program for pdfs has yielded no results, IE still uses Nuance in-browser.

Anyone have any thoughts on how to change IE or Chrome to default to using Reader to show pdf files instead of Nuance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just change the default programs or applications that opens pdf files, make it the adobe reader. You'll have to configure it in Windows, the Default Programs in Control Panel. You'll have to do this in each computer.

Comment: Already tried this, it still opens it with Nuance in browser.